# how to write our own program in JM reference software

Tags: encoder

I want to model a background for some 20 frames and treat that as the reference frame.Iam having the mathematical model and I want to know the file where this modification has to to be done.Could I do the modification in C:\JM\lencod\src

Answer (score 0):

go to JM/bin folder. you can make a copy of encoder.cfg and edit it.